# date/time calculations in Teradata

Tags: date, time, teradata

please help me to calculate beginning of the day,end of the day,beginning of month,end of month(along with time upto 3 places) in teradata. I want something like this '2014-03-01 00:00:00.000'; thanks

Comment: What version of Teradata? What have you tried?

Comment: Version Teradata 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT DATE
     , CAST(DATE AS INTEGER) AS DateInteger
     , CAST(((DATE / 100) * 100) + 1 AS DATE) AS MonthBegin
     , CAST((((DATE / 100) +1 ) * 100) + 1 AS DATE) AS NextMonthBegin
     , CAST((((DATE / 100) +1 ) * 100) + 1 AS DATE)  - 1 AS MonthEnd
     , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
     , CAST(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP(3)) AS DayBegin
     , CAST((CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) AS DATE) + 1) AS TIMESTAMP(3)) - INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND AS DayEnd
```

*** Edit ***

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE
     , CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT( DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1 as MonthBegin
     , ADD_MONTHS(( CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT (DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1), 1) as NextMonthBegin
     , ADD_MONTHS(( CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT (DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1), 1) - 1 as MonthEnd
     , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
     , CAST( CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (3) AS DATE) AS TIMESTAMP (3)) AS DayBegin
     , CAST(( CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (3) AS DATE) + 1) AS TIMESTAMP (3)) - INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND AS DayEnd;
```

From here you should be able to get to Month Begin, Month End, and Next Month Begin as timestamps. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Hello Rob Paller: This part started failing in my script its was working ok before  CAST((((DATE / 100) +1 ) * 100) + 1 AS DATE)  - 1 AS MonthEnd. nothing changed the version of teradata is same.Its giving invalid date error

Comment: Do you know what date value is causing the failure?

Comment: I am taking current date

Comment: See second SQL statement.

Comment: thanks a lot.that worked fine. But why the first suddenly stopped working .it worked for few months perfectly fine.

Comment: The first one results in 2014-13-01 which is obviously not a valid date :)